# Infinite session using Electron framework

Tags: electron, session-management

We are building a desktop client(using Electron framework) which will communicate with a remote server via REST API. We want our desktop client to be in the logged-in state for an infinite time. 
I am aware of this fact that credentials of user need to be stored securely for this purpose. 
But how can we achieve this Electron framework so that it renews user session continuously on session expiration?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the Webstorage, generally, it is the same behavior as for example facebook does, your browsers saves some kind of authentification token.

But this also has a drawback because it can be stolen through XSS, one trick to prevent this while still beeing logged in infinitly is to update the token on each connection to the server, also make sure to use HTTPS otherwise the token can be grabbed from the network connection.

```
// write to storage    
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// read key from storage
console.log(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));

// delete key from storage
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```